# How to disable overriding function in c programming

Tags: c

Please check my example code.

```
#include <string.h> 
char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src);

int main () 
{ 
  char str1[] = "Geeks";   
  char str2[] = "Quiz";   

  puts("str1 before memcpy "); 
  puts(str1); 

  /* Copies contents of str2 to sr1 */
  strcpy (str1, str2); 

  puts("\nstr1 after memcpy "); 
  puts(str1); 

  return 0; 
} 

char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src){
      *dest = '1';
}
```

How to avoid this type overriding by linker library.

Comment: What is the actual problem? If you don't want to use the function you declared. Why even declare it?

Comment: I am developing an encryption library. I need to hide actual data from a user (data only executable). But some hackers overriding my function. How to stop it?

Comment: In C, if you are linking with a standard library then you cannot override a function, this is a C++ feature.  Your duplicate function will error during linking.

Comment: The only way "overriding" is possible in C is library interposition: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-1386/chapter3-26/index.html

Comment: "Hackers overriding your function ?". You need to give more details since I doubt your hackers have modified your C files...

Comment: @phoxis or use weak symbols (not standard C though).

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean interesting thing to know, there are a ton of such interesting things in different implementations.

Comment: If a hacker is overwriting content of your executable, then there is no way to prevent "overriding" a function.   If you're really worried about that, set things up so the program runs in context of a specific account for which logins are disabled, with protections so a hacker can't modify it.

Comment: Even if you get the linker to use the implementation you want, the compiler may treat `strcpy` specifically and not use either your routine or the one in the library. The names of functions in the standard C library are reserved, and the behavior of defining them yourself is not defined by the C standard. GCC has a `-fno-builtin-strcpy` switch to deal with this.

Comment: A person who has access to your source and modifies it, isn't a hacker, but a burglar... None of this makes any sense. Get a better lock on your door, change computer password, problem solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace your C code.

I prefix all my globals (even `static` ones and even in executables) with the prefix of my library and that makes name collisions with libc a non-issue (it also simplifies moving code, amalgamating code or making formerly `static` functions `extern`).

In general you can't stop a C program author that links your library from interposing over your library's functions (their program, their rules).
If you're a shared-library author on a platform like Linux, you can, however, prevent them from trivial linker-based overriding of your library's internal functions. One way to do it is with library-private (hidden) symbol aliases:

Example (relies on non-standard C extensions and on using a shared
rather than static library) :

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
cat > h.h<<EOF
void a(void);
void A(void);
void b(void);
EOF
cat >  mylib.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include "h.h"

void b_(void);
void a()
{
    b(); //overridable
}
void A(void)
{
    b_(); //non-overridable
}
void b(void)
{
    puts("b");
}
__attribute((visibility("hidden"),alias("b"))) typeof(b) b_ ;
//^ the b_ hidden function (unlike a static function)
//can be used from other translation units of the same shared lib
//but not from outside

EOF

gcc -c mylib.c -fpic
gcc mylib.o -o libmylib.so -shared

cat > main.c <<EOF
#include "h.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void b(void) { puts("my b"); }
int main()
{
    puts("do a"); a(); puts("===");
    puts("do b"); b(); puts("===");
    puts("do A"); A(); puts("===");

}
EOF
gcc main.c $PWD/libmylib.so
./a.out
```

Output:

```
do a
my b
===
do b
my b
===
do A
b
===
```

More info for example in [How to Write Shared Libraries](https://www.slideshare.net/KarlFrank99/dsohowto) by U. Drepper.

Comment: Could you add the output of your program ?

Comment: `__attribute__` or __attribute?

Comment: @ArshidKV They're both the same.